# EPUB reader for Android

Tags: java, android

How do I improve this code for reading an epub file? The code is as follow:

```
package org.example.mymenu;

import java.awt.print.Book;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
//import java.util.List;

//import org.example.mymenu.Book;
//import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.TocReference;
//import nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.epubReader;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
//import android.graphics.Bitmap;
//import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Log the info of 'assets/books/testbook.epub'.
 *
 * @author paul.siegmann
 *
 */
public class Eread extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    try {
      // find InputStream for book
      InputStream epubInputStream = assetManager
          .open("/assets/sample.epub");

      // Load Book from inputStream
      Book book = (new Eread()).readEpub(epubInputStream);


    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("epublib", e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  Book readEpub(InputStream epubInputStream) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Eread epubReader = new Eread();
      try {
        Book book = epubReader.readEpub(new FileInputStream("sample.epub"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }


}
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what to review here. There is virtually no notable code there other than the initialization of a Book object. The only thing think I can think of is: handle the exceptions better.

Answer (score 3):

1. According to the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), *9. Naming Conventions*, I'd call the class `EpubReader`. The name should be a noun, and try to avoid abbreviations which makes the code harder to read.
2. Couldn't the `readEpub` method be `private`? Why has it default access?
3. The `readEpub` does not use the `epubInputStream` parameter. Why is it read `sample.epub`? It looks like a test code. Furthermore, this class seems really incomplete. `onCreate` creates a new `Eread` instance then calls its `readEpub` method. The `readEpub` creates (again!) a new `Eread` instance (`epubReader`) then calls its `readEpub` method. It's an endless loop.
4. `onCreate` is an instance method, so you could call `readEpub` without creating a new `Eread` instance:

   ```
   Book book = readEpub(epubInputStream);
   ```